# AngularJS - HTML snapshot for dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gruntjs

I am working on an AngularJS project where we need to have HTML snapshots of the pages in the site for crawler bots.

For the snapshots I am using the `grunt-html-snapshot` https://github.com/cburgdorf/grunt-html-snapshot which is working fine for static pages.

In the URL section I am able to add the routes as:

```
urls: [
  '/',
  '/resources/blog',
  '/resources/webinars',
  '/resources',
  '/clients',
  '/services',
  '/work',
  '/about-us',
  '/contact-us'
],
```

This takes the snapshots for the pages. But how to take the snapshots of dynamic pages with routes like `/resources/blog/:title` to take the snapshots of the individual blogs?

Thanks

Comment: from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location: "To allow indexing of your AJAX application, you have to add special meta tag in the head section of your document:
`<meta name="fragment" content="!" />`

This will cause crawler bot to request links with _escaped_fragment_ param so that your server can recognize the crawler and serve a HTML snapshots. For more information about this technique, see [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html)"